# UpdateModel is not updating "deep" property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. At a certain point I get a FormCollection in a Controller method that I want to use to update a model. In the collection not all of the values are properties of that model and the property to be updated is an item from a list, and that list is also an item from another list. Something like this (I hope this is clear):

```
propertyToUpdate --> model.Items[0].Subitems[0].SomePropertyClass.Value;
```

I tried this in my Controller:

```
UpdateModel(model);
```

The problem is that this is not working and I assume it has something to do with the fact that the reflection is not working. I went searching and stumbled upon [**this article**](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-using-controller-updatemodel-when-using-a-viewmodel/). So I understand that using the prefix-parameter solves the problem. But not in my case, as the properties lie "deeper" in the model as items from a list.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

**Update:**

Here's the EditorTemplate for the property:

```
@model Q95.Domain.Property

<li>
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Description) : 
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Quantity.Value)
    @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Quantity.Unit.Description)
    <br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Quantity.Value)
</li>
```

This template is called like this:

```
<ul>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SegmentRequirement.MaterialRequirements[j].Properties)
</ul>
```

Is this enough code or is there something still missing?

**Update2:**

Ok, in all the sub-properties I defined parameterless constructors and now I call:

```
UpdateModel(segmentRequirement, "SegmentRequirement", form.ToValueProvider());
```

This updates the model, but everything from MaterialRequirements is re-instantiated... :S

Comment: The rendered html is missing. EditorFor can render anything.

Comment: DisplayFor will render labels which aren't sent to the server. so you will get only the Quantity. 2. don't write .Value ==>  @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Quantity)

Comment: 'Value' is needed as it is a property of the class 'Quantity'. The class also has a property 'Unit'. So 'Value' should be there, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I didn't pay enough attention. i thought it's Nullable<int>. Any why, what exactly is missing in the `Model Binding`?

Comment: What do you mean ModelBinding? This is a value I get from the FormCollection: "SegmentRequirement.MaterialRequirements[0].Properties[0].Quantity.Value". And not the value from the TextBox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5627/discussion-between-gdoron-and-abbas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateModel works fine on "Deep properties".
The problem is probably the data in the collection you get isn't equal to the properties names.
Check 3 places to see the values you get from the page

1. The form values.
2. The route data
3. The query string

In exact that order.

The **keys** should **match** you model **properties names**.

---

**Update:**
How to match the keys to properties names?
The input id will be the key you will get, change the the ids to match your properties names, or even better, use the [HtmlTextBoxFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703535.aspx.) helper:  see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx) article:

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting me on the way! Now how can I get the data to have the same value as the name of the property to update?

Comment: @Abbas, Updated the post with extra explanations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create flattened ViewModel and then use that to populate the view, and later synchronize it with the real model.

Comment: You can't flat collections...!

Comment: Q95.Domain.Property can be flattened. Anyway, the OP would do himself a favor if he simplified the data he is presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your model and your view, if you are not using htmlhelper, you then have to understand the naming convention very well in order to make the model binding work with your model. so the first thing in first is to show us your model and view.